# yii - how to redirect after 10 seconds

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, yii

I am new to the yii framework, and I can't see to find any information or forums about how to redirect after 10 seconds has pass on a page. for example after resetting your password, I would like to redirect to the login page but only once its been 10 second to allow the user to see the message display on the page.

Comment: Simple JavaScript works just fine: `window.location.href = 'new url';`. You can embed it in your page with `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag()` to register such a meta tag for the redirect:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag("10;url={$returnUri}", null, 'refresh');
```

This will generate:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=/foo/index.php?r=site/catalog"/>
```

which will produce a redirect after waiting 10 seconds.

It's not necessary to use yii if you're making a simple redirect. You can simply use Javascript and do this:

```
window.location.href = 'http://yournewURLgoeshere.tld/foo/bar';
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Yii doesn't have a refresh method, but what is wrong with:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Refresh:10;url='. $this->createUrl('controller/action'));
}
```